# Pig script using php

Tags: php, apache-pig, cassandra-0.7

Is it possible to run pig script in any other programming language like PHP?

Comment: Which pig? This one http://wiki.apache.org/pig/PigTutorial ?

Answer (score 0):

No. Currently you can embed pig script only in python and javascript.

From the latest doc - http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/cont.html
"To enable control flow, you can embed Pig Latin statements and Pig commands in the Python and JavaScript scripting languages using a JDBC-like compile, bind, run model. For Python, make sure the Jython jar is included in your class path. For JavaScript, make sure the Rhino jar is included in your classpath."